# How to group two fields under a single key?

Tags: mongodb

I'm playing around with MongoDB and had an idea, but can't find a way to implement it:

There are `stores` and `customers`, so a single `store` can sell items to different `customers` and those can buy from the same `store` multiple times.

Let's assume I have a document called `purchases` to keep track of every purchase being made:

```
purchases = [{
  store_name: 'Store A',
  customer_name: 'Customer One',
  price: 89
},
{
  store_name: 'Store A',
  customer_name: 'Customer Two',
  price: 190
},
{
  store_name: 'Store A',
  customer_name: 'Customer Two',
  price: 10
}]
```

If I where to return data grouped by Store and Customer? I want to fetch something like:

```
{
  store_name: 'Store A',
  purchases: [{
    customer_name: 'Customer One',
    value:89
  }, {
    customer_name: 'Customer Two',
    value: 200
  }]
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with mongo alone?

Comment: What do you mean by "present data" ? In the command line?

Comment: Yes, it can be on mongo shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this aggregation

first `$group` is to group by store and customer name to sum value

second `$group` is to group by store name and push customer and value to an array

```
db.purchases.aggregate(
[
    {$group : {
        _id : {store_name : "$store_name", customer_name : "$customer_name"},
        value : {$sum : "$price"}
        }
    },    
    {$group : {_id :"$_id.store_name", purchases : {$push : {customer_name : "$_id.customer_name", value :"$value"}}}}
]
)
```

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly what I meant! Thanks!